# Azure Logic Apps : Unitill loop using Response Header Value

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-logic-apps

First forray in playing with Logic Apps.

I am trying to create an App that grabs data from an HTTP API and loops untill a header value is removed.

In this test, I'm using the [Freshservice API](https://api.freshservice.com/#pagination) which gives me a value in the header for the "next" page

I'm trying to use the value in the "Link" to firstly check if there are any more pages, but also interested how to use that value in the HTTP URI for the next request.

I can Run my trigger which will run and load the JSON and Headers, but i'm struggling to find any information on how to refrence the header value in the requirements.

Appreciate any help or links for reading

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers are additional and optional pieces of information in the form of name/value pairs that travel between the client and the server with the request and/or the response.

From the above statement we understand that you are facing problem in reading the HTTP headers and how to write HTTP headers. That is Reading HTTP headers from the request and writing HTTP headers in request.

If you want to add a custom header in your dot NET Core API response or you need to read a header from the request, you can check this [link](https://www.abhith.net/blog/asp-net-core-handling-custom-header-on-request-response/).

Check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.headers?view=netframework-4.8#examples) from Microsoft to read the header values from your http request.

Also check the following document for more information.

1. [HTTP response header](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/http-response-headers-asp-net-core/).
2. [Request API](https://developers.freshservice.com/docs/request-api/).

If this doesn't solve the problem, then could you elaborate the problem statement and give more insights so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It sounds about right, but not sure how I can use the provided information within the Azure Logic Apps? Not sure if I can do C# code?

Answer (score 0):

You are listing several questions.

1. How to reference the header value from the HTTP response?

You can do it by using an `Expression` (instead of `Dynamic content`) in the action you want to reference it in. E.g. if you HTTP action is called `HTTP` then the expression would look like this: `outputs('HTTP')?['headers']?['link']`

2. How to use that value in the HTTP URI for the next request?

You could use the expression above directly in the URI field of your next HTTP request, but since your next request could also have the `link` header which you'd need to process, it makes sense to create a variable and use the `Set variable` actions to make sure the variable always holds the latest `link` value. Then you could use the variable in the URI field of your next HTTP request.

3. How to loop until the `link` header value is empty?

In general, your workflow would look as follows:

- Initialize a string variable (let's call it `link`) with the initial URI value that you want to use in your HTTP action.
- Create an [`Until`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#until-loop) loop using `@equals(variables('link'), '')` as a a parameter. The actions below should be inside this [`Until`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#until-loop) loop.
- Create an HTTP action (let's call it `HTTP`), selecting the `link` variable in the Dynamic content of the API field.
- Set the `link` variable to expression `outputs('HTTP')?['headers']?['link']`